# PHP Display Array Elements

Tags: php, arrays, xml, csv, if-statement

I'm trying to have a PHP file format an XML file that is generated by my site then strip all the redundant information and output a CSV file.  I have everything working fine except if there are multiple line-items only the first item is being submitted.  Here's the XML and PHP I'm working with and I can't figure out why it's not looping with the foreach command.

XML

```
<line-items type="array">
<line-item>
    <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
    <fulfillment-status nil="true"/>
    <gift-card type="boolean">false</gift-card>
    <grams type="integer">5000</grams>
    <id type="integer">56789</id>
    <price type="decimal">199.99</price>
    <product-id type="integer">123456</product-id>
    <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
    <requires-shipping type="boolean">true</requires-shipping>
    <sku>SKU2006-001</sku>
    <taxable type="boolean">true</taxable>
    <title>Sledgehammer</title>
    <variant-id type="integer">654321</variant-id>
    <variant-title nil="true"/>
    <vendor nil="true"/>
    <name>Sledgehammer</name>
    <variant-inventory-management nil="true"/>
    <properties type="array">
    </properties>
    <product-exists type="boolean">true</product-exists>
    <fulfillable-quantity type="integer">1</fulfillable-quantity>
    <tax-lines type="array"/>
</line-item>
<line-item>
    <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
    <fulfillment-status nil="true"/>
    <gift-card type="boolean">false</gift-card>
    <grams type="integer">500</grams>
    <id type="integer">98765</id>
    <price type="decimal">29.95</price>
    <product-id type="integer">12345</product-id>
    <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
    <requires-shipping type="boolean">true</requires-shipping>
    <sku>SKU2006-020</sku>
    <taxable type="boolean">true</taxable>
    <title>Wire Cutter</title>
    <variant-id type="integer">54321</variant-id>
    <variant-title nil="true"/>
    <vendor nil="true"/>
    <name>Wire Cutter</name>
    <variant-inventory-management nil="true"/>
    <properties type="array">
    </properties>
    <product-exists type="boolean">true</product-exists>
    <fulfillable-quantity type="integer">1</fulfillable-quantity>
    <tax-lines type="array"/>
</line-item>
```

And the PHP to format it;

```
    $line_items = $order->{'line-items'};
$line_item = $order->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'};
$count_line_item = count($line_item);
    $item_sku = $order->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'}->{'sku'};
    $item_qty = $order->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'}->{'quantity'};
    $ship_to_email = $order->{'email'};
    $item_price = $order->{'line-items'}->{'line-item'}->{'price'};

    $item_array = array($line_item);

    foreach($item_array as $line_item) {

        $csv =
            $order_number.','.
            /*$order_contact_id.','.*/
            $first_name.','.
            $last_name.','.
            $order_date.','.
            $shipping_address1.','.
            $shipping_address2.','.
            $shipping_city.','.
            $shipping_province.','.
            $shipping_country.','.
            $shipping_zip.','.
            $shipping_phone.','.
            $item_sku.','.
            $item_qty.','.
            $ship_to_email.','.
            $item_price;

    };
```

I'm looking to output something like this ***1234,Steve,Shipper,2015-01-09 08:40:30,123 Shipping Street,,Shippington,KY,US,K2P0S0,555-555-SHIP,SKU2006-001,1,jon@doe.ca,199.99*** but continuous if there's multiple items.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think you should foreach thru $line_items

Comment: @RobinValk if I do that it still only runs through once.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much transformations you need/want it can be as simple as

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('php://stdout', 'wb');

$items = new SimpleXMLElement( data() );
foreach( $items->{'line-item'} as $item ) {
    fputcsv($fp, iterator_to_array($item));
}


function data() {
    return <<< eox
<line-items type="array">
<line-item>
    <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
    <fulfillment-status nil="true"/>
    <gift-card type="boolean">false</gift-card>
    <grams type="integer">5000</grams>
    <id type="integer">56789</id>
    <price type="decimal">199.99</price>
    <product-id type="integer">123456</product-id>
    <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
    <requires-shipping type="boolean">true</requires-shipping>
    <sku>SKU2006-001</sku>
    <taxable type="boolean">true</taxable>
    <title>Sledgehammer</title>
    <variant-id type="integer">654321</variant-id>
    <variant-title nil="true"/>
    <vendor nil="true"/>
    <name>Sledgehammer</name>
    <variant-inventory-management nil="true"/>
    <properties type="array">
    </properties>
    <product-exists type="boolean">true</product-exists>
    <fulfillable-quantity type="integer">1</fulfillable-quantity>
    <tax-lines type="array"/>
</line-item>
<line-item>
    <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
    <fulfillment-status nil="true"/>
    <gift-card type="boolean">false</gift-card>
    <grams type="integer">500</grams>
    <id type="integer">98765</id>
    <price type="decimal">29.95</price>
    <product-id type="integer">12345</product-id>
    <quantity type="integer">1</quantity>
    <requires-shipping type="boolean">true</requires-shipping>
    <sku>SKU2006-020</sku>
    <taxable type="boolean">true</taxable>
    <title>Wire Cutter</title>
    <variant-id type="integer">54321</variant-id>
    <variant-title nil="true"/>
    <vendor nil="true"/>
    <name>Wire Cutter</name>
    <variant-inventory-management nil="true"/>
    <properties type="array">
    </properties>
    <product-exists type="boolean">true</product-exists>
    <fulfillable-quantity type="integer">1</fulfillable-quantity>
    <tax-lines type="array"/>
</line-item>
</line-items>
eox;
}
```

prints

```
manual,,false,5000,56789,199.99,123456,1,true,SKU2006-001,true,Sledgehammer,654321,,,Sledgehammer,,"
    ",true,1,
manual,,false,500,98765,29.95,12345,1,true,SKU2006-020,true,"Wire Cutter",54321,,,"Wire Cutter",,"
    ",true,1,
```

edit: example selecting only a few elements

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('php://stdout', 'wb');

$items = new SimpleXMLElement( data() );
$data = array(
    'onum' => 1234,
    'fname' => 'Volker',
    'sku' => 0,
    'qty' => 0,
    'shipemail' => 'foo@b.ar'
);

foreach( $items->{'line-item'} as $item ) {
    $data['sku'] = (string)($item->sku);
    $data['qty'] = (string)($item->quantity);
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
}


function data() {
    return <<< eox
<line-items type="array">
<line-item>
    <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
    <fulfillment-status nil="true"/>
    <gift-card type="boolean">false</gift-card>
    <grams type="integer">5000</grams>
    <id type="integer">56789</id>
    <price type="decimal">199.99</price>
    <product-id type="integer">123456</product-id>
    <quantity type="integer">5</quantity>
    <requires-shipping type="boolean">true</requires-shipping>
    <sku>SKU2006-001</sku>
    <taxable type="boolean">true</taxable>
    <title>Sledgehammer</title>
    <variant-id type="integer">654321</variant-id>
    <variant-title nil="true"/>
    <vendor nil="true"/>
    <name>Sledgehammer</name>
    <variant-inventory-management nil="true"/>
    <properties type="array">
    </properties>
    <product-exists type="boolean">true</product-exists>
    <fulfillable-quantity type="integer">1</fulfillable-quantity>
    <tax-lines type="array"/>
</line-item>
<line-item>
    <fulfillment-service>manual</fulfillment-service>
    <fulfillment-status nil="true"/>
    <gift-card type="boolean">false</gift-card>
    <grams type="integer">500</grams>
    <id type="integer">98765</id>
    <price type="decimal">29.95</price>
    <product-id type="integer">12345</product-id>
    <quantity type="integer">17</quantity>
    <requires-shipping type="boolean">true</requires-shipping>
    <sku>SKU2006-020</sku>
    <taxable type="boolean">true</taxable>
    <title>Wire Cutter</title>
    <variant-id type="integer">54321</variant-id>
    <variant-title nil="true"/>
    <vendor nil="true"/>
    <name>Wire Cutter</name>
    <variant-inventory-management nil="true"/>
    <properties type="array">
    </properties>
    <product-exists type="boolean">true</product-exists>
    <fulfillable-quantity type="integer">1</fulfillable-quantity>
    <tax-lines type="array"/>
</line-item>
</line-items>
eox;
}
```

prints

```
1234,Volker,SKU2006-001,5,foo@b.ar
1234,Volker,SKU2006-020,17,foo@b.ar
```

Comment: I have to strip a lot of that info out of there, from the line-item section I only need three fields and I have it selecting the fields right now, would this way still be easier?

Comment: not really, but I still would put those values in one array and then use fputcsv. Outside the foreach loop you'd put the data like shipping_address1 etc into this array and then within the loop you'd just replace the values from the line-item element and call fputcsv.

Comment: Wicked, I'm giving this a shot right now. I just have to ask is the return <<< eox dynamic? Will it be updating when it loads the items? So if there are 6 items instead of two the xml there will reflect that?

Comment: `function data()` is only in the example to make it a `Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example`, see http://sscce.org/ . You would probably use something like http://docs.php.net/simplexml_load_file or similar instead. For the meaning of `<<< eox` see http://docs.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: The SimpleXMLElement was returning an error but the simplexml_load_file isn't however all I'm getting is a single line of **,,,2015-01-09 10:30:41,,,,,,,,,,,** so only the timestamp is appearing

Comment: Try as I may, I can only get it to display the first line.

Comment: Sounds like the document is broken and therefore libxml can't parse it (completely). Take a look at the error control functions at http://docs.php.net/libxml which may help you narrowing down the error(s) .